# How to say 'It's perfect for me'

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

My owner sent me an email saying "See attachment how the table is displayed."

I like how the table is shown, and I want to say "it's nice for me" or "it's perfect for me."

What is the correct expression I should use?

Comment: You can say, "That works for me."  or "The table looks great." or just, "Nice!"

Comment: It's I suggested to change the table. Your sentence is simply

Comment: If you suggested to change the table, then it was "*not* nice for you".  In that case it's "That doesn't quite work for me, how about this instead." or "That doesn't look quite right." or "I had in mind something different." etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exact situation is slightly unclear, as "my owner" would usually only be spoken by a slave of his master, which I highly doubt.

If you are giving unconditional approval, you would just say, "It's nice," or "It's perfect."

If you are emphasizing that you approve, where others might disagree, you can say, "I think it's nice," or "I think it's perfect."

If the table has been customized to meet your needs, you might say, "That will work nicely for me," or "That will work perfectly for me." This usage of "work" means that it will serve its function.

Also, be aware that "nice" can imply a range of degrees of approval, depending on how much it is emphasized. "Perfect" is always very strong approval, unless it is being used ironically. "Nice!" is stronger than "that is nice," which is stronger than "that's nice."